# What's the best approach/setup for fast remote mysql connections?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-replication

This is my scenario:

I have a website, let's call it **SITE1**. It stores user's information in a mysql DB. Both website and MySQL db are in the same server.

However, I have other websites that also must to have access to this DB used by **SITE1**. The problem is, these other websites cannot be in the same location as **SITE1**, they have to be in other geographical locations. Some locations are close to where **SITE1** is hosted (10ms), and others aren't (80ms).

my other websites should not only be able to access the DB used by **SITE1**, but they also must be able to update it.

What concerns me is the time each website will take to access and update the DB. Also, I need to ensure that two websites are not trying to update the same row at the same time, or I can corrupt things, right?

What would be the best setup for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

you can use locks writing during a transaction:

```
mysql_query("LOCK TABLES mytest WRITE;");
```

Comment: In this case, if another server tries to update a certain row that is locked, it will just wait until it gets unlocked?

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly what you mean, as I am dealing with the same problem currently.

You can setup a master/master db replication, which is very complicated, as you need close contacts to the db-admin.

I decided to use post messages, using wrapper functions. For this you only need to add a field to each table, which contains a ID for your post request, transmitted together with the post.

After that you have access to the entries like this

INSERT INTO mytable (a,b,actionID) VALUES ('value_a','value_b','timestamp_by_php_plus_username');

UPDATE mytable SET c = 'value_c' WHERE actionID = 'timestamp_by_php_plus_username';

Good luck